# Does infimum exist on any subset of this partial order.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $S$ be a set. For $\tau$ and $\tau'$ be topologies on $S$. Declare $\tau \leq \tau'$ meaning $id: (S,\tau) \rightarrow (S,\tau')$ is continuous. This is a partial order on the set of all topologies on $S$. 
Prove there exists an infimum for any subset of this poset.

Attempt: I can first prove $\tau \subseteq \tau'$ iff $id: (S,\tau') \rightarrow (S,\tau)$ is continuous.

I need to show a supremum exists in the partial order by $\subseteq$. So, for $\kappa$ a collection of topologies on $S$, I need to show a topology $\tau_{\kappa}$ on $S$ with the following properties:

1. For $\tau \in \kappa$, then $\tau \subseteq \tau_{\kappa}$
2. For $\tau'$ a topology on S for which, for each $\tau \in \kappa, \tau \subseteq \tau'$,then $\tau_{\kappa} \subseteq \tau'$.

So if $\tau_{\kappa} = \bigcup\limits_{U \in \kappa}U $. This satisfies 1) but might not be a topology as indicated from Munkres excercise 4a)

How could I formally show there is a supremum?

Comment: Your title and first paragraph asks one thing, but the rest of your post asks the opposite.

Comment: I meant supremum exists in the partial order formed by $\subseteq$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\tau \le \tau'$ if and only if, for all $\mathcal{U} \in \tau'$, $\mathcal{U} = \operatorname{id}^{-1} (\mathcal{U}) \in \tau$. That is, $\tau$ is *finer* than $\tau'$. So, to find an infimum of a subset $T$ of the poset, we need to find the coarsest topology that is finer than every topology in $T$.

Let $B$ be the union of all topologies in $T$. While $B$ is not necessarily a topology, it makes a perfectly good sub-basis. Form the topology $\tau_0$ by taking all arbitrary unions of finite intersections of $B$. Such a topology is clearly finer than all elements of $T$.

Suppose $\tau_1$ is a lower bound of $T$. Then, $\tau_1$ contains every set in $B$. Moreover, it must contain every finite intersection of sets in $B$, and every arbitrary union of such intersections. In other words, $\tau_1 \le \tau_0$, showing that it is the infimum of $T$.

Comment: Discrete topology, but that need not be the supremum for a collection of topologies

Comment: It is a supremum for the poset of all topologies, which I thought was the question. Are you looking to show that any subset of this poset posesses an infimum? If so, you should probably make this clearer in the question.

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant. I shall edit the question.

Comment: I have not yet read about basis. Is that necessary for doing this problem? Is there a way of doing without  using that

Comment: I did throw out the sub-basis term, but I also did explain how to turn $B$ into a topology: take the set $B'$ of finite intersections of elements of $B$ (which contains $B$), and then let $\tau_0$ be the set of unions of elements of $B'$.

Comment: How do you know $\tau_0$ is a topology?

Comment: That's the one part of the proof that I omitted. It's very simple to show that $\tau_0$ is closed under arbitrary union, as all of its elements are arbitrary unions of $B'$. For finite intersections, use$$\bigcup_{i \in I} \mathcal{U}_i \cap \bigcup_{j \in J} \mathcal{V}_j = \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times J} \left(\mathcal{U}_i \cap \mathcal{V}_j\right).$$

Comment: Well, firstly to prove finite intersections, you only need to establish the intersection of two sets, as any finite intersection will follow easily by induction. An element in $\tau_0$ takes the form $\bigcup_{i\in I} \mathcal{U}_i$, where each $\mathcal{U}_i \in B'$. Note that $B'$ is closed under intersection, since each element is a finite intersection of elements of $B$. So, $\mathcal{U}_i \cap \mathcal{V}_j \in B'$, which means the right hand side of the above equality lies in $\tau_0$.